# how is it possible to run a rails app without development.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails3 app that  that has no environments/development.rb but runs just fine locally (with pow, thin or passenger).

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are defaults--all the default version of that file does is set some config overrides.

Comment: but (at least in rails 2) if you leave out a development.rb file the app will error out when you go to start it? did this change?